# I'can see balance in my Bitcoin-cli

Tags: key, private, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have a mini server for Bitcoind and simply wallet site.
I can receive bitcoins... I can see tx in BlockChain. Everything is ok!

But; 
I'm entering terminal;
`bitcoin-cli getbalance` or `bitcoin-cli getbalance mybitcoinadress`
Result everytime;
0.00000000

But; I dump privkey mybitcoinadress, and I entered my phone wallet and I can see Right Balance!

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution on this?

Answer (score -1):

There's no such API that returns balance for a given address.

```
bitcoin-cli getbalance  [account] [minconf=1]
```

If `[account]` is not specified, returns the server's total available balance.

If `[account]` is specified, returns the balance in the account.

[Link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) for further study.